# How to use delegate in javascript

Tags: javascript, delegates

I try to make todo list app with javascript, I have function to create new each item (li elements) like that

```
  todoView: function (todo) {
    var controller =  todoController.todoList;
    console.log('controller', controller);

    var item = document.createElement('li');
    item.setAttribute('class', 'todoItem');

    var inpCheckbox = document.createElement('input');
    this.setAttributes(inpCheckbox, { 'type': 'checkbox', 'class' : 'itemList'} );

    var lbContent = document.createElement('label');
    lbContent.innerHTML = todo.getContent();

    var btnRemove = document.createElement('button');
    console.log('id', this.id)
    this.setAttributes(btnRemove, { 'class': 'remove', 'id' : this.id} );
    // btnRemove.setAttribute('id', this.id);

    //item append each element
    item.appendChild(inpCheckbox);
    item.appendChild(lbContent);
    item.appendChild(btnRemove);

    console.log('item', item);

    //ul append each item
    document.querySelector('#todoListView').appendChild(item);
  },
```

but in the end file I set the handle event for all li item have class `.remove`

```
var deleteItem = document.getElementsByClassName('remove')
for(var i = 0; i < deleteItem.length; i++) {
  deleteItem[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    todoController.removeTodo(i);
  });
}
```

But now I have issue that I can't call `.remove` class, because it just create into `todoView` function. It to be contain difference block. In jquery I can use delegate to resolve it, but I don't know how to fix it in js pair. Pls help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
var deleteItem = document.getElementsByClassName('remove')
for(var i = 0; i < deleteItem.length; i++) {
  deleteItem[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    todoController.removeTodo(i);
  });
}
```

you'll want

```
todoListView.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   if(e.target.classList.contains('remove')){
     todoController.removeTodo(e.target);
   } 
});
```

However, I think your `removeTodo` function is flawed

Comment: your explain it too clear, but for the code demo you show it not work on my practice. Can you check it again for me. Let see the code at https://codepen.io/dienvm/pen/jmdmKY, thanks @JaromandaX

Comment: sorry but I still not clear, I will creare new button before I find elements with class `.remove`, right? it like that
`

var btnRemove = document.createElement('button')
var deleteItem = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(deleteItem, function(item, i) {
    item.addEventListener("click", function() {
        todoController.removeTodo(i);
    });
});

`